# No images in HTML mode on TOMCAT

Tags: gwt, tomcat, jasper-reports

```
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_DIR_NAME, "images/jasper_tmp/");
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "/images/jasper_tmp/");
```

I'm using jasper report in a GWT project.
My PROD platform is TOMCAT 5.5 on Win2003.
I've tried on TOMCAT 7 / Windows 7 too.

These lines are called from the server side of the application in a servlet. So I cannot use static method from com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.

It seems that my problem is similar as [jasper reports with HTML Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830043/jasper-reports-with-html-format)

In DEV mode, in Eclipse, every things is ok. All images are display when I get my jasperreport in HTML.

In my PROD environment, it is a TOMCAT server, images in the jasper report are not display in HTML. On PROD server, `exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_DIR_NAME, "images/jasper_tmp/");` generate `images/jasper_tmp/` in %TOMCAT_HOME%, not in the deployment directory of my app.
On filesystem, I've `%TOMCAT_HOME%/images/jasper_tmp/`, I expect `%TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps/my_project/images/jasper_tmp/`.

**How could I pass the images as parameters ?** (if it is possible)... as suggested in the answer.
Do I need to install Apache Web Server to make any rewrite rule ? My PROD server have TOMCAT only.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use context path?

Comment: If you mean using http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html#getServletContext() and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath() like `getServletContext().getContextPath()`, so yes.

Comment: I meant modifying jetty-web.xml to make your dev and deploy path same. Anyway if it solved your problem you can post it in comment and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `Firefox with Firebug Plugin` or `Chrome with Chrome Dev Tool` or IE8 Dev Tool to investigate whether its `image path` or `css` or `javascript` error and update the question with more details.

Firebug - getfirebug.com

Chrome - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview

IE8 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/07/improved-productivity-through-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools.aspx

1) You need not go for apache proxying with rewrite rules unless its performance requirement of serving static resources.

2) You can tweak you image paths for DevMode and Production Mode with GWT.isProdModel , GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(), GWT.getModuleName()  or getModuleBaseForStaticFiles()

```
if (com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.isProdMode()){
 //Path Used in production mode
} else {
 //Path Used in dev mode
}
```

**Edit**
The above information helps on client side. On server side the Jetty server **context** path varies from you webapp deployment in server like tomcat. You can fix it to be same as tomcat by following the instructions mentioned here https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/a8OsRmMSaMg/discussion

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
"http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd"> 
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext"> 

        <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set> 

</Configure>
```

Comment: This app is only use by one or two persons as internal app so it do not need hight level of performance. This is the reason why I want to avoid Apache HTTP server solution. Thank for the answer, I'll try this solution...

Comment: I cannot use these static method from com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT because I cannot use it from server side of application.

Comment: There are two GWT classes. One in "shared" and other in "client". I am referring to GWT 2.5 . Not sure whether they are available in older code.

Comment: `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()`, `GWT.getModuleName()` or `GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles()` are from com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT. I cannot use it so... :o(